# Are all adapters for TRRS to TRS the same?

Tags: audio, connector, cables, microphone, trrs

I want to connect an audio device (specifically, a phone) with a TRRS output port to a second device with a TRS microphone input (an audio recorder).

I tried [one such adapter](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B088T1MRVQ) but it does not work.

I heard that each manufacturer uses their own version of TRRS which would require a different adapter. How can I figure out which one I need?

I also tried patch cables, both TRS to TRS and TRRS to TRRS, but the recorded audio is very poor quality. Will incorrect cable connections cause audio quality issues, or is there another cause?

Comment: "Questions on the use of electronic devices are off-topic as this site is intended specifically for questions on electronics design." I don't think this is a valid close reason here -- this question is not about the use of a specific electronic device, but rather about interfacing two different devices.  I've suggested some small edits to make it more generic as well. I don't have the reputation to vote to reopen, though.

Comment: I would add "how can I determine which variant of TRRS my device uses?"

Answer (score 1):

As you've discovered, there is no standard meaning to each contact in a TRRS connection. Some devices are built to be backwards-compatible with older TRS connections, and as such have ground in position 3, putting the mic in the sleeve. Other devices put ground at the sleeve and the mic in position 3. (And if your device also outputs video over TRRS, all bets are off.)

The cable you linked doesn't specify its internal wiring. It is possible that your cable's TRRS sleeve is ground, but your phone is providing ground on the second ring. You can use a multimeter's continuity checker to see which TRRS contact is connected to each contact on the TRS end.

But for this particular use case, I think a standard TRS-TRS cable should work just fine. I don't know of any TRRS audio I/O device that can't handle a TRS connection shorting the microphone to ground, as this is a fairly common use case. If you're getting bad sound quality, it likely won't be because of mismatched connections, and probably has a different root cause. Do other TS/TRS microphones, plugged into the recording device, record with acceptable quality? If not, the problem is likely inside the recorder. Can your audio output device plug into a standard set of computer speakers and produce good audio? If not, the problem is likely inside the phone. If both work, try a higher-quality cable.

I don't know which recorder you have, but it's also possible it only has a TS connection jack, and though it's probably just leaving your R channel floating, it's theoretically possible that your recorder is shorting the phone's R output to ground. If it's a TS jack, you'll probably want a stereo-to-mono converter to make sure you capture both channels regardless.